# Camera and sprite move with similar velocity but JITTER appears

Tags: opengl-es, libgdx, opengl-es-2.0

I have a sprite that I advance in the world along with a camera. They both move at the same speed . However , I see a slight jitter of the moving sprite . Should that be possible given the fact that I add the same Y value to both the camera and the sprite?

(NOTE: The filter for the sprite is set to LINEAR)

```
public void AdvanceWorld(){ 
    float delta = Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();      
    float delta_64_srsz = delta * 64f;
    float velo = spaces.world_velocity * delta_64_srsz;
    spaces.spaceshipAdvance(velo);      
    camera.position.y += velo;
}   

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    AdvanceWorld();
    ...
    batch.begin();      
    ....
            batch.end();
            ...
    camera.update();    
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);     
}

public void spaceshipAdvance(float velocity){
    sprite.setPosition(sprite.getX(), sprite.getY() + velocity);
    thrusters.setPosition(thrusters.getX(), thrusters.getY() + velocity);   
}
```

However, after the framerate stabilises around 60fps the jitter fades and is only slightly noticeable. It's only noticeable when there is variation in FPS.

Also, if I decrease the velocity( delta_64_srsz = delta * 16f ) the jitter disappears. It seems that be big velocity I'm using causes this. Can I sync the camera with the sprite so I can use high velocities without the jitter?

Comment: High velocity multiplied with delta time causes slight variations due to delta time fluctuation to some degree. If this is for a mobile game it's best *not* to animate your characters with delta time, instead assume the fps is always 60 and then make sure it never drops below just because of what you draw or do in your code. But if it does, at worst the game will slow down for a short time period.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I'll stop using delta if I manage to get constant 60FPS once I finish the game and have all my textures inside one or two atlases. For now though I'll drop the velocity to 32f instead of 64f. The jitter is well reduced.

Comment: Why are you updating the camera and setting the projection matrix *after* you've rendered your world?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid moving the camera yourself and instead have the camera follow the sprite.

This can be achieved as follows:

First make an `OrthographicCamera` like this:

`OrthographicCamera cam = new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight());`

Next in your `render()` method update the `cam` position with the sprite `x` and `y` positions like this:

`cam.position.set(sprite.getX(), sprite.getY(), 0);`

After that you should set the projection matrix to `cam.combined` like this:

`batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);`

And finally update your camera:

`cam.update();`

You should put these last three steps together in the `render()` method like this:

```
public void render(float delta){
    // other stuff ...
    cam.position.set(sprite.getX(), sprite.getY(), 0);
    cam.update();
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
    // other stuff ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using meters instead of pixels? It's always nice practise not to use pixels.

Comment: It's because I deleted alot of code containing **delta * 64** which would have been calculated each time so I saved that inside a variable instead. The above code didn't help , but thanks!